# How to make work target="_blank" on iPhone at InAppBrowser?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, redirect

How to make work target="_blank" on iPhone at InAppBrowser.
I try:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://192.168.1.3/mobilesiteapp/', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,presentationstyle=fullscreen,toolbarposition=top,clearsessioncache=no,hidden=yes');
}
```

};

But it doesn't work. It's only works with target="_system". But if I use it I can't to hide url and bottom browser toolbar. How to fix it?

Comment: What doesn't work? What should it do? If it doesn't work, why do you need to hide the URL and bottom toolbar?

Comment: Redirect doesn't work. Because I need to open other site in window then application start. For this I use cordova.InAppBrowser

Answer (score 0):

You have specified hidden=yes, which will hide the browser window. Try the following:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://192.168.1.3/mobilesiteapp/', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,presentationstyle=fullscreen');
```

Comment: It's not working on my iPhone 5S. Page is opened, but no chance for redirect. I correct me code at start of this page. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. This code works in your case?

Comment: I have projects that use this and it works.When debugging, are you hitting the cordova.InAppBrowser.open line?

Comment: Where? No look up. It's all.

Comment: Debug the app, put a breakpoint on the cordova.InAppBrowser.open line and see if there is anything logged in the console. Maybe a try catch and see if you get an error message or something?

Comment: What a you use for debug?

Comment: I use visual studio as I develop in windows. What application do you develop your software with?

Comment: So you use visual studio to emulate iPhone. Do you?

Comment: I use WebStorm for Angular 2 and Ionic 2 application. But it is on my website. So I want to use PhoneGap to open needed to me URL with Ionic 2 application.

Comment: You need to debug the app to see if it is calling the cordova.InAppBrowser.open line? That line of code should open the website with no problems. You need to see why it isn't, and debugging the app is the only way you will get more information on this

Comment: Surely that refers to running it on a mac, and not on an iPhone (iOS)

Comment: What kind of emulator for iOS/iPhone you are using?